# App hangs on --> 'Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext' on websphere

Tags: websphere, rsa

When I try to deploy the app ear through RSA on websphere, the deployment hangs on the following line:

Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext.
Initialization successful.

And then server times out.
How can I troubleshoot this problem?
Which log should I see? The logs folder is rather confusing with too many files.
When I deploy the app through the admin console by building .ear first, it deploys fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to publish the application within RSA/RAD. The logs are the same whether you deploy through this or via the admin console.

SystemOut, SystemErr and trace.logs would be my first points of check.

I am assuming your application spits out this info line:
**Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext. Initialization successful**

When does it do this? This would likely occur after the application has been deployed and the application is in its starting phase.

I would check this location

/profiles//installedApps/

Replace all the <...> with the respective values in your environment.

Once deployment is successful you should see a directory with the name of your application eg.

This tells you that the application is installed in your Test environment server.

Publishing effectively does two activities - Install and Start the application.

Once you see the EAR here you know that your problem lies in your application start up activities.

Try and see if you can narrow down from there.

HTH
Manglu

Comment: I found the logs.thank you. But the starting of the app still hangs

Comment: Kaushik, Now that we know that the error is in application starting phase, try getting a thread dump to see where it is stuck. This would tell you what the JVM is trying to do when this "hang" occurs.